# QueryString is always empty ASP.net Core 3.1

Tags: model-binding, asp.net-core-3.1

The query string I use is always empty. I have no idea why, and have tried for hours with 
The HttpContext.Request returns all other parts of the URL except the querystring.

With this url https://localhost:44394/Trackers/Create?Place=Vision_College

and this Model

```
 [BindProperties(SupportsGet = true)] 
    public partial class Tracker
    {  
     [FromQuery(Name = "Place")]  //populates it from the query 
      public string Place { get; set; }
     ...}
```

and this controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Name, Phone, Place")] Tracker tracker)
        {
```

[image: Empty Query]

Comment: How exactly are you posting this URL?

Comment: The URL is coming from a QR code and loads the page correctly. Just the Querystring is not being accepted. It seems that the problem is that the Query string itself held in the the Request is always empty. Its not getting as far as putting it into the Property. Is there something I am missing that goes  in the startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found an answer. 
I was trying to use it in the POST of the CREATE, when I should have been using it in the GET part of CREATE  [image: Using GET to get querystring]

Thanks for everyones help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the query parameters in httpPost you should use, `[FromQuery]` inside your arguments. Follow this

Your DTO class would be,

```cs
public class Tracker
{
  [FromQuery(Name = "Place")]
  public string Place{ get; set; }
}
```

In your controller class

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromQuery]Tracker tracker)
{

}
```

**Note:** If your query parameters match with the model property names, specifically annotating the properties would not be necessary.

Better you can get by body itself since this is a post request. otherwise make this as a get request. If converting to get by body, simply use `[FromBody]` in endpoint arguments instead of `[FromQquery]`

Comment: The URL is coming from a QR code and loads the page correctly. Just the Querystring is not being filled. It seems that the problem is that the Query string itself held in the Request is always empty. Its not getting as far as putting it into the Property. Is there something I am missing that goes  in the startup?

Comment: From where are you accessing `HttpContext` ? Post the full source code please

Comment: It comes from an empty  if (HttpContext.Request.Path.HasValue) {} that I have later in the code. Otherwise its just a stock Create Post generated from Scaffolding.  I am just trying to get the property Tracker.Place to hold the query string that comes in on the URL. HttpContext allows me to see the entire URL and its components, its not used as such, at this stage. I did try  BusinessName = HttpContext.Request.Query["Place"].ToString();  but its empty